# Writing a javascript function that just prints details of a form to another html page when a button is clicked.

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to take information from a form, one is a number that can be changed by the user and the other is a constant floating point number. When the user inputs a number, they then press submit, which is when I want the output to be printed to my confirmation webpage. I've not seen much online on this so if anyone has some advice or just a pointer to some online material for me that would be greatly appreciated. Also should mention that I'm not allowed to use any javascript libraries to do this just in case. Thanks

Comment: **"Not Allowed"** Sounds like a school assignment.

Comment: You can't show things on other webpages with JavaScript. Once the next page loads, the JavaScript will be reloaded and have no memory of what was in the form. You either have to use just one page or use a PHP or other sort of backend to do this.

Comment: Javascript could easily display the data on the same page. If a separate confirmation page is required, a server side language would be the obvious answer. Sounds like you are missing some important details

Comment: You could hack something together with cookie / localstorage but I doubt a beginner assignment would be looking for that

Comment: GET parameters could also work. But more important, @OP: What have you tried so far? Questions only looking for online resources are likely to get closed here, so you should include some code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ach, I'm feeling sympathetic. I *assume* you're doing this on the same page (if not, you're probably in the wrong place & want PHP I guess).

If it is, here's something extremely crude to get you started, with some comments.

Note that there is a truly vast amount of information on JS and the DOM, given it's essentially the primary purpose of the language. Which suggests you didn't really look very hard, but I get it's difficult to know what you're looking for at first. MDN is generally excellent for specifics - look up the methods used here, they'll all have better examples than mine.

```js
// Listen for a 'click' on the element with an ID of 'submit',
// and run the 'printSomeCrap' function:
document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', printSomeCrap, false)

function printSomeCrap() {
  // Grab the constant from the element with the id 'constant'
  var constant = document.querySelector('#constant').textContent
  // Grab whatever was typed in from the element with the id 'input'
  var input = document.querySelector('#input').value

  // Then find the element with the ID of 'output', and print out
  // what was just grabbed as a string:
  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = `Constant: ${constant}, Input: ${input}`
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Just type something">
<p id="constant">0.123456789</p>
<button id="submit">Then press this button</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```